# BASH: How to add text in the same line after command

Tags: linux, bash

I have to print number of folders in my directory, so i use
`ls -l $1| grep "^d" | wc -l`
after that, I would liked to add a text in the same line.
any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t want to use a variable to hold the output you can use echo and put your command in $( ) on that echo line.

```
echo $(ls -l $1| grep "^d" | wc -l ) more text to follow here
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign the result to a variable, then print the variable on the same line as the directory name.

```
folders=$(ls -l "$1" | grep "^d" | wc -l)
printf "%s %d\n" "$1" "$folders"
```

Also, remember to quote your variables, otherwise your script won't work when filenames contain whitespace.